# Como Lambda em Extension Methods com várias Lists?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Existem os seguintes Objetos:

```
public class Objeto1
{
   public List<Objeto2> PropObj1 {get; set;}
}

public class Objeto2
{
   public List<Objeto3> PropObj2 {get; set;}
}

public class Objeto3
{
   public int PropObj3 {get; set;}
}
```

Tenho uma **Lista de Objeto1** e preciso obter uma lista filtrada de **Objeto1**, apenas os que possuem a **PropObj3 == 1**:

```
List<Objeto1> listaObj1 = new List<Objeto1>();
// Suponhamos que listaObj1 já possui valores inseridos.

var resultado = listaObj1.Where(o1 => o1.PropObj1... ).ToList();
```

Neste caso, como ficaria a expressão lambda?

Estou usando **Entity Framework**.

Comment: É Entity Framework?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez é Entity Framework sim, acabei me esquecendo de colocar...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Se é Entity Framework, creio que a lista venha de um contexto, então não vou usar uma lista avulsa pra responder. Vou responder a partir do contexto mesmo, até porque a construção de uma lista a partir de um contexto de dados é completamente diferente da construção de uma lista a partir de uma operação em memória usando Linq:

```
var lista = contexto.Objetos1
                  .Where(o1 => o1.PropObj1
                                 .Any(o2 => o2.PropObj2
                                              .Any(o3 => o3.PropObj3 == 1)))
                  .ToList();
```

Em Linq puro, veja que ficaria diferente:

```
var sublist = list.PropObj1
                  .Where(o => o.PropObj2.Any(o2 => o2.PropObj3 == 1))
                  .ToList();
```

[Montei um Fiddle pra você](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LhRnSU).

Comment: Muito obrigado @CiganoMorrisonMendez, funcionou perfeitamente. Eu não conhecia esse `.Any`. Não tem ideia do quanto me ajudou!

Answer (score 8):

Acho que é isto que deseja:

```
var resultado = listaObj1
    .SelectMany(o => o.PropObj1, (objeto1, objeto2) => new { objeto1, objeto2 })
    .SelectMany(o => o.objeto2.PropObj2, (objeto2, objeto3) => new { objeto2, objeto3 })
    .Where(o => o.objeto3.PropObj3 == 1).Select(o => new { o.objeto2.objeto1.PropObj1 })
    .ToList();
```

[`SelectMany()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#overloads) serve para transforma listas de listas em uma lista sequencial única.

Eventualmente você precisa usar um `Select()` para determinar como quer o resultado.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/mnhJlk). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/C22j5j). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/FilterList.cs).

Comment: Essa resposta devolve `Objeto3`, e não `Objeto1`. Está incorreta.

Comment: É, não devolve. Não sei se entendi o que ele quer. Se for isto, vou ver o que pode ser feito.

Comment: É bastante comum AP's pedirem questões com "lambda" pra construírem expressões Linq na verdade com uso no Entity Framework, mas o Linq para o Entity Framework compila uma sentença SQL (no caso de SQL Server) ou um BSON (no caso de MongoDB ou outros bancos não-relacionais). Neste caso é legal sempre questionar o AP pra ver se o que ele quer é uma operação em lista ou uma sentença em EF. [Fiz um fork do seu Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/A6adkg). Veja que ele devolve um `Objeto3`.

Comment: Sim, eu concordo. Só não sei qual o resultado que ele espera.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez acho que agora está de acordo com o que ele quer. A sua está melhor mas está fica como uma alternativa. Talvez ainda precise de alguma adaptação no `select` depois eu acerto isto.

Comment: Nunca testei desta forma. Vou até verificar essa alternativa. Pode ser boa para outros cenários.