# Como juntar sublistas com Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Imagine que tenho as seguintes classes:

```cs
public class Pedido
{
    public int PedidoId { get; set; }
    public List<ItemPedido> Itens { get; set; }
}

public class ItemPedido
{
    public int ItemPedidoId { get; set; }
}
```

E preciso retornar todos os pedidos com seu *PedidoId* junto com seus itens com o respectivo *ItemPedidoId*, isso em uma única collection, algo como:

```cs
var pedido1 = new Pedido() { PedidoId = 1 };
pedido1.Itens.Add(new ItemPedido() { ItemPedidoId = 1 });
pedido1.Itens.Add(new ItemPedido() { ItemPedidoId = 2 });

var pedido2 = new Pedido() { PedidoId = 2 };
pedido2.Itens.Add(new ItemPedido() { ItemPedidoId = 1 });
pedido2.Itens.Add(new ItemPedido() { ItemPedidoId = 2 });

var pedidos = new List<Pedido>();
pedidos.Add(pedido1);
pedidos.Add(pedido2);

// Como fazer aqui? ...
var pedidoItens = from p in pedidos 
                  //select new { p.PedidoId, ? }                        

/* ...Para retornar isso
    * PedidoID, ItemDoPedidoID              
        1     ,   1
        1     ,   2
        2     ,   1
        2     ,   2
*/
```

Qual é a melhor forma de chegar a este resultado utilizando Linq?

Comment: Isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80066/101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se utilizando `Constains` é a melhor forma, já que no seu `Pedido` não há referencia para o `ItemPedido`, mas da pra fazer da seguinte forma:

```
var resultado = from i in pedidos.SelectMany(e => e.Itens)
                from p in pedidos
                where p.Itens.Contains(i)
                orderby p.PedidoId
                select new { p.PedidoId, i.ItemPedidoId };
```